# Overriding mixins functions in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to override a mixin function in Vue.js?

Maybe it's my mistake to be using Mixins in an OOP fashion, but I have a `Page` component with subtle variations but a common shared set of functions. To achieve this, I'm using an `AbstractPage` component and add it as a mixing for each `Page`.

The problem comes when one specific `Page` requires a slightly different behaviour in one of the functions. Out of the box, Vue doesn't override the `parent` function, but it adds both in an array and executes them sequentially.

Is there any way to override mixins functions? Or any idea on a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: So far this is what I'm doing: `if (this._events['df.submit'].length > 1) return false`. It's an awful solution.

Comment: The methods should overwrite each other. Are you talking about lifecycle methods?

Comment: Sorry, it's events. And I don't think methods override each other.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/0m3eogp0/ it looks like they do.

Comment: Have you removed the jsfiddle? Can I take a look?

Comment: You are right, they don't! From the docs: `Options that expect object values, for example methods, components and directives, will be merged into the same object.`. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as Bill Criswell points out in the comments, this is only a problem with `events` and other hook functions. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html?redirect=true):

> For example, hook functions with the same name are merged into an
> array so that all of them will be called.

But `methods`, for example, won't. From the docs:

> Options that expect object values, for example methods, components and
> directives, will be merged into the same object.

The solution is just then to execute a method from an event, instead of executing logic inside the event declaration.